# Weighting several returns over different time frames

Tags: returns

I have a set of annualized returns over 4 time periods: 10yr, 5yr, 3yr and 1yr.

Is there a way to weight each return to have a "more representative" return?

Comment: I know this question sounds odd, but I overheard that there is a typical approach to dealing with different time frames in returns. Maybe a exponential-based set of weights?

Comment: What's the goal of your analysis?

Comment: Just presentation, I won't use it for any calculation

Comment: Ignoring any GIPS-related issues, I think the weighted returns are too complicated for most presentations. That depends on your audience, of course, but people understand a table showing a few different periods of returns so I wouldn't try to fight that too much. If all else fails, do what your boss says.

Answer (score 1):

You can weight the returns and use them in calculations as shown below.

From this site:-

http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/giovanni/additional/users-manual/G3_operation_time_series_stats.shtml

The weighted mean is

[image]

and the weighted standard deviation is

[image]

So, making up some annualised returns for time spans, 1 yr, 3 yrs, 5 yrs & 10 yrs:

```
r = {0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04}
```

and some weights based on decaying relevance with, say `τ = 2`

```
a = {e^(-1/τ), e^(-3/τ), e^(-5/τ), e^(-10/τ)}
```

and fixing their total to be 1

```
w = a/Σa
```

> {0.660361, 0.242933, 0.0893701, 0.00733595}

the weighted mean return is 0.0144 and weighted s.d. is 0.00972

Note, by using weights that sum to 1 the formulae are simplified, Σw and (Σw)^2 = 1.